# Where can I find the full text for Bastion levels?

Tags: bastion

Specifically, I'd like to read the story of the Who Knows Where levels. I'm sure the full text is out there somewhere, but my Google-fu is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are links to transcripts of the "Who Knows Where" narration that I found on the Bastion Wiki:

- [First level](http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Zulf%27s_Pipe#Plot) (Zulf's Pipe)
- [Second level](http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Zia%27s_Stockpot#Plot) (Zia's Stockpot)
- [Third level](http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/The_Kid%27s_Bedroll#Plot) (The Kid's Bedroll)

According to the edit dates on the wiki, these were added on Dec. 15th and Dec. 29th 2011, so your Google-fu would likely have succeeded if it had taken place a couple of weeks later :-).

Answer (score 9):

My google-fu has likewise failed me, so this might not exist already.  However, I have a couple of ideas.

One would be to watch videos of the "Who Knows Where" levels on YouTube.  [First level](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUmpO2md80Q&feature=related), [second level](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icAXzTMnp8E&feature=related), [third level](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qUyf1fPwO4&feature=related).

They're only about 10-15 minutes each, so transcribing them wouldn't take long.

My second thought is that if you own the PC version of the game, you may be able to read the subtitle text out of the game's data files, although I don't know what the format of these files is.  Additionally, getting the script out in sequential order might be a challenge.

Perhaps someone else will come along with a better link, but this is about the best I could come up with.

Comment: The game is still young. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: The Kid tried to hide his disappointment, but it was plain as the black on a squirt.  He slinked off with his half-answer, but we knew he'd be back.  He'd never give up hope.

Comment: The subtitles are stored in simple text files (at least for the Humble Bundle version).